# UISearchBar can't jump to the correct DetailVC

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

The idea is when I press one of the search result, he should point to The matching DetailVC, But he does not do that, if i choose any of the search result, it just jumps to the first line in the total list.
can someone help me, thanks a lot

[Screenshot，maybe it helps better to explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAnyl.png)

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var myData = Indications.readFromBundle()
    var data: [Indications]!

    let searchResultsController = UITableViewController()
    var searchcontroller: UISearchController?
    var resultArray = [Indications]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        searchcontroller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchcontroller?.searchBar
        searchcontroller?.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
        searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if let searchWord = searchcontroller?.searchBar.text{
            resultArray = myData.filter({
                (thisIndication) -> Bool in
                if thisIndication.name.lowercased().contains(searchWord.lowercased()) {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            })
            self.searchResultsController.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue,sender: Any?){
        if segue.identifier == "SegueToDetail" {
            let dest = segue.destination as? DetailVC

            let selectedIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            if let selectedRow = selectedIndexPath?.row {
                dest?.data = myData[selectedRow]
            }
        }

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(myData[indexPath.row].name)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueToDetail", sender: nil)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.tableView {
            return myData.count
        } else {
            return resultArray.count
        }

    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        if tableView == self.tableView {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            let row = indexPath.row
            cell.textLabel?.text = myData[row].name
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = UITableViewCell()
            let row = indexPath.row
            cell.textLabel?.text = resultArray[row].name
            return cell
        }


    }

}

import UIKit

class DetailVC: UIViewController {

    var data:Indications!

    @IBOutlet weak var titleNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var punktzahlLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var indikationTextLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var beschreibung: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var indikationTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addTapGestureToMyImg()

        if data == nil { return }

        titleNameLabel.text = data.name

        punktzahlLabel.text = data.numOfPoint

        indikationTextView.text = data.indication

        beschreibung.text = data.beschreibung

        let name = data.name.replacingOccurrences(
            of: "ü", with: "ue")
        myImg.image = UIImage(named: name)
    }

    func addTapGestureToMyImg() {
        let tapGesture=UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleIntoBigViewImg))
        myImg.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        myImg.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
    }

    @objc func handleIntoBigViewImg() {
        print("cklik")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotobigimg", sender: data.name)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "gotobigimg" {
            if let bigImgViewController=segue.destination as? BigImgViewController {
                bigImgViewController.infoFromDetailVC = sender as? String
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please fix code alignment

Comment: This is often because the selected indexPath does not match the index in the data model (`data` array in your case). You can set up another array like `filteredData` which gets added to based on the search results. Use a Boolean flag variable like `isSearching` and then the detail view controller gets sent either `data[indexPath.row]` or `filteredData[indexPath.row` depending on the value of `isSearching`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use separate array for your main content and filtered contents. This way indexes will match to what you are seeing on filtered contents.

Pseudo code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "gotobigimg" {

      if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

        let searchBarScopeIsFiltering = searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex != 0
        let isFiltering = searchController.isActive && (!searchBarIsEmpty() || searchBarScopeIsFiltering)

        if isFiltering {
          infoFromDetailVC = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
        } else {
          infoFromDetailVC = array[indexPath.row]
        }

        if let bigImgViewController=segue.destination as? BigImgViewController{
            bigImgViewController.infoFromDetailVC = sender as? String
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

[Referenced from RayWenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: @ kthorat  Thanx you very much for helpful answer. I tried to corerect my App, But I am failed, I think it is because I am just beginner in Swift / or all programming language. I have a request: kann you please visit my GitHub page, there saves my project (this is my first App project) , And can you please correct my project there in GitHub? Thanks again!!**[link](https://github.com/sten-danli/OhrakupunkturProject/tree/master)**

Comment: Hey @DanLi I think you should give another go, it will be good for long run. If you get stuck, fee free to reach out. Download sample app from RayWenderlich it has working example -> https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2017/10/CandySearch_4_Finished.zip